# OneSignal SDK for Xamarin: there is no definition of inFocusDisplayType

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, onesignal

The Xamarin.Forms sample code on https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup (section 2.1A) seems a bit outdated. I had to change several package objects, like `OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE` to `Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE`.

One line I couldn't convert rightaway to the current SDK:

```
OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification;
```

So where has `inFocusDisplayType` moved in the SDK?

Complete code:

```
public partial class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyApp.LoggingInPage());

        //Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging  
        OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

        OneSignal.Current.StartInit("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID")
        .Settings(new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
            { Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt, false },
            { Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL, false } })
        .EndInit();

        OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification;
               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ??

        // The promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse function will show the iOS push notification prompt. We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission (See step 7)
        OneSignal.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
    }
```

Comment: they have [github](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Xamarin-SDK), but I couldnt find `inFocusDisplayType` there. You can raise an issue and ask there if you dont get an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it would work nowadays:

```
OneSignal.Current.StartInit("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID")
    .Settings(new Dictionary<string, bool>() { 
        { Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt, false }, 
        { Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL, false }
    })
.InFocusDisplaying(Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)  // <-- !
.EndInit();
```

(Thanks to *enkaradag*, who responded to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Xamarin-SDK/issues/194#issuecomment-623036977))